# Unable to boot a meteor project with only two lines of code

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to learn meteor and going through meteor tips, and the second line in the js file "PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');" causes it to be unable to run. It says i have a duplicate file in the sub-directory, but i'm unsure how that is possible because the only three files i have in there are the leaderboard.css, leaderboard.html, and leaderboard.js.

I'm unsure how to format to make this more readable, thanks for the help!

here are the logs:

```
C:\Users\jeffr_000\Documents\leaderboard>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\jeffr_000\Documents\leaderboard ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150406-12:20:14.063(-7)? (STDERR)
W20150406-12:20:14.065(-7)? (STDERR) C:\Users\jeffr_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\pa
ckages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules
\fibers\future.js:245
W20150406-12:20:14.065(-7)? (STDERR)
throw(ex);
W20150406-12:20:14.066(-7)? (STDERR)
      ^
W20150406-12:20:14.066(-7)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/member/insert' is a
lready defined
W20150406-12:20:14.066(-7)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461
:1
W20150406-12:20:14.066(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/
underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20150406-12:20:14.066(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (pa
ckages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1459:1)
W20150406-12:20:14.067(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._de
fineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:904:1)
W20150406-12:20:14.067(-7)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo
/collection.js:209:1)
W20150406-12:20:14.067(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\leaderboard.js:3:14
W20150406-12:20:14.067(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\leaderboard.js:5:3
W20150406-12:20:14.068(-7)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\jeffr_000\Documents\leaderb
oard\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
W20150406-12:20:14.068(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150406-12:20:14.068(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\
jeffr_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\
dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20150406-12:20:20.151(-7)? (STDERR)
W20150406-12:20:20.151(-7)? (STDERR) C:\Users\jeffr_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\pa
ckages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules
\fibers\future.js:245
W20150406-12:20:20.152(-7)? (STDERR)
throw(ex);
W20150406-12:20:20.152(-7)? (STDERR)
      ^
W20150406-12:20:20.152(-7)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/member/insert' is a
lready defined
W20150406-12:20:20.152(-7)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461
:1
W20150406-12:20:20.153(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/
underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20150406-12:20:20.153(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (pa
ckages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1459:1)
W20150406-12:20:20.153(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._de
fineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:904:1)
W20150406-12:20:20.154(-7)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo
/collection.js:209:1)
W20150406-12:20:20.154(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\leaderboard.js:3:14
W20150406-12:20:20.154(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\leaderboard.js:5:3
W20150406-12:20:20.155(-7)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\jeffr_000\Documents\leaderb
oard\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
W20150406-12:20:20.155(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150406-12:20:20.155(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\
jeffr_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\
dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150406-12:20:26.038(-7)? (STDERR)
W20150406-12:20:26.038(-7)? (STDERR) C:\Users\jeffr_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\pa
ckages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules
\fibers\future.js:245
W20150406-12:20:26.038(-7)? (STDERR)
throw(ex);
W20150406-12:20:26.038(-7)? (STDERR)
      ^
W20150406-12:20:26.038(-7)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/member/insert' is a
lready defined
W20150406-12:20:26.039(-7)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461
:1
W20150406-12:20:26.039(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/
underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20150406-12:20:26.039(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (pa
ckages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1459:1)
W20150406-12:20:26.040(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._de
fineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:904:1)
W20150406-12:20:26.040(-7)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo
/collection.js:209:1)
W20150406-12:20:26.040(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\leaderboard.js:3:14
W20150406-12:20:26.041(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\leaderboard.js:5:3
W20150406-12:20:26.041(-7)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\jeffr_000\Documents\leaderb
oard\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
W20150406-12:20:26.041(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
W20150406-12:20:26.042(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\
jeffr_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\
dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
```

Comment: Are you defining your own insert method for the collection in your js file?

Comment: Nope the only lines of code are "new Mongo.Collection('players');"  and

"PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often when you encounter error like `A method named '/member/insert' is a
lready defined`, it means you are creating `new Mongo.Collection('member')` more than one time.

Perhaps you are doing it in a `Array.forEach` function (which calls multiple times if your array has more than 1 element).

From your error logs it looks like it is caused by the `fn` in your `_.each(array,fn)` at `server\boot.js`.